# Example of Scala NonFatal

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock a situation where a nonfatal is thrown by my code and it does something else after recovering. Something like:

```
Try {
// do something
} recover {
  case NonFatal(e) => println("I want to get to this point")
}
```

And I'm trying to use mocks to be like `when(mock.doMethodThatCallsTry).thenThrow(non-fatal)` but I can't find an example of a non fatal I can throw to emulate this situation after looking around on scala docs.

Comment: never mind, the results threw me off. Worked fine with a runtime exception

Answer (score 0):

NonFatal is object of scala that defines non-fatal errors. Here is definition

```
object NonFatal {
/**
* Returns true if the provided `Throwable` is to be considered non-fatal, or false if it is to be considered fatal
*/
    def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
    // VirtualMachineError includes OutOfMemoryError and other fatal errors
    case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
             case _ => true
     }
     /**
     * Returns Some(t) if NonFatal(t) == true, otherwise None
     */
     def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = if (apply(t)) Some(t) else None
}
```

Meaning every exception thrown (except fatal ones) will be catch in the case

```
case NonFatal(e) => println("I want to get to this point")
```

Because in unapply non-fatal exceptions are Some(t) while Fatal one are None. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html for reference.

You can just throw any non-fatal exception.

Comment: Yes I knew the definition of a NonFatal exception, but didn't know an example of one (which I asked for). I used a simple RuntimeException and it worked.